# Parallel::Forkmanager -> populate a hash of hashes of arrays from child processes

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, parent-child, hash-of-hashes

I have this piece of code that I'd like to parallelize (for reference):

```
my (%fastas, %counts);

foreach my $sample ( sort keys %AC2 )
{
    foreach my $chrom (sort keys %{ $AC2{$sample} } )
    {
        foreach my $pos ( sort { $a <=> $b } (@{ $allAC2{$chrom} }) )
        {
            my $allele;

            #position was genotyped in sample
            # or is AC=1, but was also found in AC=2
            if( grep(/\b$pos\b/, @{ $AC2{$sample}{$chrom} }) || grep(/\b$pos\b/, @{ $finalAC1{$sample}{$chrom} }) ) #"\b" is for word boundary -> exact word match
            {
                $allele = @{ $vcfs{$sample}{$chrom}{$pos} }[2]; #ALT allele
            }
            #Make sure all SNP positions are in all samples
            #Fill with reference genome allele information
            else
            {
                #Fill with reference genome allele information
                $allele = substr( @{ $ref{$chrom} }[0], $pos-1, 1); #or die "$sample, $chrom, $pos";
            }
            push ( @{ $fastas{$sample}{$chrom}{$pos} }, $allele);
            push ( @{ $counts{$chrom}{$pos} }, $allele) unless (grep {$_ eq $allele} @{ $counts{$chrom}{$pos} } );
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the child processes need to populate the two hashes. I've search and only found a few example showing how to use "run_on_finish" to return variable from the child processes. The "problem" is that all the examples/tutorials that I've found are always returning scalars.

Is it possible to pass a hash (or 2 hashes) out of the child process?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: References are scalars.

Comment: See: http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/Parallel-ForkManager-1.19/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm#Data_structure_retrieval   PFM uses Storable to pass structures back to the parent process. The second example shows the child sending back arbitrary data.

Comment: Given passing back a significant amount of data, I tend to favour (worker) threads type model for this. Thread::Queue and parallelism.

Comment: @Sobrique, the VCF files I'm working with (my script input) are not that big (baterial genomes). But I'll try to keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: @Ben Grimm, that link was helpful. There is a reference to a hash in there. Fiddling with FM for a couple of days and reading back those examples, they all make more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't return hashes, return hash references.**

References in Perl are scalar values. So all you need to do is to return a reference to `%fastas` and `%counts`.

Here is a hacky example taken from the documentation of Parallel::Forkmanager. It builds a hash in each child process with as many elements as the input data suggests. It return a reference to that hash to the parent, where the callback picks it up and inserts it into the `$overall` data structure.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(2);

my $overall; # will hold all results in the parent
$pm->run_on_finish( sub {
    my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal, $core_dump, $data_structure_reference) = @_;

    $overall->{$pid} = $data_structure_reference;
});

DATA_LOOP:
foreach my $data (1 .. 10) {
  # Forks and returns the pid for the child:
  my $pid = $pm->start and next DATA_LOOP;

  my %child_result = map { $_ => 1 } 1 .. $data;

  $pm->finish( 0, \%child_result );
}

$pm->wait_all_children;
p $overall;
```

The output looks like this:

```
\ {
    1224   {
        1   1
    },
    1225   {
        1   1,
        2   1
    },
    1226   {
        1   1,
        2   1,
        3   1
    },
    1228   {
        1   1,
        2   1,
        3   1,
        4   1
    },
    1230   {
        1   1,
        2   1,
        3   1,
        4   1,
        5   1
    },
    1231   {
        1   1,
        2   1,
        3   1,
        4   1,
        5   1,
        6   1
    },
    1232   {
        1   1,
        2   1,
        3   1,
        4   1,
        5   1,
        6   1,
        7   1
    },
    1233   {
        1   1,
        2   1,
        3   1,
        4   1,
        5   1,
        6   1,
        7   1,
        8   1
    },
    1234   {
        1   1,
        2   1,
        3   1,
        4   1,
        5   1,
        6   1,
        7   1,
        8   1,
        9   1
    },
    1235   {
        1    1,
        2    1,
        3    1,
        4    1,
        5    1,
        6    1,
        7    1,
        8    1,
        9    1,
        10   1
    }
}
```

If you want to return two data structures, wrap them in an array reference.

```
$pm->finish( 0, [ \%fastas, \%counts ] );
```

Answer (score 2):

I just thought I's publish my solution:

```
my (%fastas, %counts);

#setting up the forking process
my $nCPU = Sys::CPU::cpu_count();
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager -> new($nCPU);

$pm->run_on_finish(sub {
    my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal, $core_dump, $data_structure_reference) = @_;

    %fastas = (%fastas, %{ $data_structure_reference->{fas} });
});

my @mySamples = sort keys %AC2;
my $s = $mySamples[0];

foreach my $sample (@mySamples)
{
    my $pid = $pm->start and next;

    my %allSeqs;

    foreach my $chrom (sort keys %{ $AC2{$sample} } )
    {
        foreach my $pos ( sort { $a <=> $b } (@{ $allAC2{$chrom} }) )
        {
            my $allele;

            #position was genotyped in sample
            # or is AC=1, but was also found in AC=2
            if( grep(/\b$pos\b/, @{ $AC2{$sample}{$chrom} }) || grep(/\b$pos\b/, @{ $finalAC1{$sample}{$chrom} }) ) #"\b is for word boundary -> exact word match"
            {
                $allele = @{ $vcfs{$sample}{$chrom}{$pos} }[2]; #ALT allele
            }
            #Make sure all SNP positions are in all samples
            #Fill with reference genome allele information
            else
            {
                #Fill with reference genome allele information
                $allele = substr( @{ $ref{$chrom} }[0], $pos-1, 1); #or die "$sample, $chrom, $pos";
            }

            push ( @{ $allSeqs{$sample}{$chrom}{$pos} }, $allele);
        }
    }
    $pm -> finish(0, { fas => \%allSeqs });
}

$pm -> wait_all_children();


#List ALT alleles found at each position
foreach my $sample ( sort keys %fastas )
{
    foreach my $chrom ( sort keys %{ $fastas{$sample} } )
    {
        foreach my $pos ( sort keys %{ $fastas{$sample}{$chrom} } )
        {
            my $allele = @{ $fastas{$sample}{$chrom}{$pos} }[0];
            push ( @{ $counts{$chrom}{$pos} }, $allele) unless (grep {$_ eq $allele} @{ $counts{$chrom}{$pos} } );
        }
    }
}
```

I had to remove %counts from the main loop and compute it separately because it had to refer to it's own values (from the parent process) while being process in child processes (I hope this explanation makes sense!).

Thanks for the help everyone, I was much appreciated!
Marco